# problema con plugin ideal forms 3 para jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugin

Estoy armando un sistema que utilice html + css + php + ajax + jquery, hasta ahora he estado usando trozos de codigo para armar el sistema y todo bien sin embargo tengo un problema con un plugin para jquery llamado ideal forms (v3) que quiero usar para la creacion y validacion de los formularios en tiempo real, el problema es que el codigo deberia cargar una formulario dentro de un div pero al hacerlo la estructura del formulario se daña asi que quisiera ayuda para saber cual es la causa

codigo

prueba.php(como deberia verse el formulario):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="librerias/jq-idealforms-master/css/jquery.idealforms.css">


</head>

<body>
<div style="width: 700px; position: absolute; top: 100px;">
<div class="idealsteps-container">
<nav class="idealsteps-nav"></nav>
<form action="" autocomplete="off" class="idealforms">
<div class="idealsteps-wrap"> 

<!-- Step 1 -->

<section class="idealsteps-step">
<div class="field">
<label class="main">Username:</label>
<input name="username" type="text" data-idealforms-ajax="ajax.php">
<span class="error"></span> </div>
<div class="field">
<label class="main">E-Mail:</label>
<input name="email" type="email">
<span class="error"></span> </div>
<div class="field">
<label class="main">Password:</label>
<input name="password" type="password">
<span class="error"></span> </div>
<div class="field">
<label class="main">Confirm:</label>
<input name="confirmpass" type="password">
<span class="error"></span> </div>
<div class="field">
<label class="main">Date:</label>
<input name="date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" class="datepicker">
<span class="error"></span> </div>
<div class="field">
<label class="main">Picture:</label>
<input id="picture" name="picture" type="file" multiple>
<span class="error"></span> </div>
<div class="field">
<label class="main">Website:</label>
<input name="website" type="text">
<span class="error"></span> </div>
</section>


<div class="field buttons">
<label class="main">&nbsp;</label>
<button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</section>
</div>
<span id="invalid"></span>
</form>
</div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="librerias/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="librerias/jq-idealforms-master/js/out/jquery.idealforms.js"></script>

<script>

$('form.idealforms').idealforms({

silentLoad: false,

rules: {
'username': 'required username ajax',
'email': 'required email',
'password': 'required pass',
'confirmpass': 'required equalto:password',
'date': 'required date',
'picture': 'required extension:jpg:png',
'website': 'url',
'hobbies[]': 'minoption:2 maxoption:3',
'phone': 'required phone',
'zip': 'required zip',
'options': 'select:default',
},

errors: {
'username': {
ajaxError: 'Username not available'
}
},

onSubmit: function(invalid, e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#invalid')
.show()
.toggleClass('valid', ! invalid)
.text(invalid ? (invalid +' invalid fields') : 'All good!');
}
});

$('form.idealforms').find('input, select, textarea').on('change keyup', function() {
$('#invalid').hide();
});

$('form.idealforms').idealforms('addRules', {
'comments': 'required minmax:50:200'
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
$('.prev').show();
$('form.idealforms').idealforms('prevStep');
});
$('.next').click(function(){
$('.next').show();
$('form.idealforms').idealforms('nextStep');
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

prueba2.php(donde esta el div que va a contener el formulario):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="librerias/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts_prueba.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="asd"> <a id="cargar">cargar</a> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

script de carga

```
$(document).ready( function (){

   $("#cargar").click(function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $( "#asd" ).fadeOut(250, 
                       function(){$("#asd").load("prueba.php", 
                           function(){$("#asd").fadeIn(250); });
                                 });
                                  });
});
```

Comment: Hola David. Si tienes una duda concreta es mejor que expongas el código concreto y en ningún caso un link de descarga externo.

Comment: no se porque no me entendiste pero la cuestion es que necesito cargar un formulario dentro de un div con jquery pero al hacerlo el formato del formulario se daña, y necesito saber porque se daña, ya comprobe que se daña cuando lo envio con el script que acabo de colocar, asi que quiero saber si para arreglar el problema debo cambiar el script o el plugin

Comment: y porque no se puede colocar un link al codigo? que tiene de malo?

Comment: En ningún lado digo que no se entienda. No es válido un link externo porque nada garantiza que no sea un link malicioso ahora o en un futuro. O bien que el link deje de ser funcional y entonces la pregunta no tendría sentido. Ahora has añadido código más concreto. La comunidad se encargará de reabrir la pregunta o añadir comentarios si lo creen necesario.

Comment: lo de no enterder lo saque de la advertencia al principio, pero supongo que es una respuesta generada por el sistema y ahora que ya explicaste las razones del detalle del link creo que nos entendemos mejor, gracias por la aclaratoria

Comment: Ningún problema :). Efectivamente es un mensaje automático con un link que es de tu interés. Mira algunas preguntas con muchos votos y veras que la tuya tiene mucha explicación. Lo mejor es reducir la explicación lo más concreto posible para acotar el máximo la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: asi esta mejor la pregunta?